# My search results page isn't loading any data

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a blog and using Express and ejs to render the page. I have an Article Schema that has a category key that lists random values.

```
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  category: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["tv", "movies", "music"],
  },
});
```

Inside my catalog route page I have this GET request for when a user loads a search results page.

```
router.get("/article/search/:id", article_controller.search);
```

And this is the function attached to the GET request.

```
exports.search = async function (req, res, next) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  Article.find({}, "title")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .exec(function (err, list_articles) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("search", {
        article_list: list_articles,
        id: id,
      });
    });
  console.log(id);
};
```

Inside my search ejs page I have this code

```
<% article_list.forEach(function(article) { %>
  <% if (article.category === id) { %>
    <div class="article"> 
      <p class="title"> <a href=<%= article.url %>><%= article.title %> </p></a>
      <p class="category"> <%= article.category %> </p>
      <p class="author"> written by: <%= article.author %> </p>
    </div>
 <% } else { %>
     <p>No Articles Match This Query</p>
 <% } %>
<% }); %>
```

And finally, on my index ejs I have these `a` links.

```
<li><a href="/catalog/article/search/tv">TV</a></li>
<li><a href="/catalog/article/search/movies">Movies</a></li>
<li><a href="/catalog/article/search/music">Music</a></li>
```

Using `console.log` I've determined the `req.params.id` is properly rendering the value to whichever `a` link I'm clicking on. Ex: `movies`.

**What I'm trying to do**

What I've been doing is creating random articles and adding in a proper category. What I'm trying to do now is have a search page that only shows the articles with the category of whichever `a` link I clicked on from the home page. So if I select movies from the home page, I want the search page to only show movies with the category of `movies`. Right now I have about 20 articles posted in my database. The only thing that shows up when I click on one of the `a` links is the header, sidebar and the `else` code repeated 20 times.

```
No Articles Match This Query

No Articles Match This Query

No Articles Match This Query

etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify on which field you want to find.
So if you want to find on title field, you need to use like this:

```
  Article.find({title: "title"})
```

Comment: ...and check `<% if (!article_list.length) %>` for `No Articles Match This Query`, instead of inside the loop

Comment: Thank you! I added `category` to that and it fixed it. I can't believe it was that simple. One thing I'm trying to understand is the `!article_list.length`. I put that outside the loop and nothing happened. `<% if (!article_list.length) { %><p>No Matches</p><% } %>`